# Does gem 'mongoid', '~> 4' equal to gem 'mongoid', '>= 4'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, version, bundler

I know what `'mongoid', '~> 3.1.2'` mean. But if the version has only one number, what does it mean? Does gem 'mongoid', '~> 4' equal to gem 'mongoid', '>= 4'?

Answer (score 3):

[`From the documentation`](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic-version-constraint):

> Most of the version specifiers, like >= 1.0, are self-explanatory. The
>   specifier ~> has a special meaning, best shown by example. ~> 2.0.3 is
>   identical to >= 2.0.3 and < 2.1. ~> 2.1 is identical to >= 2.1 and <
>   3.0. ~> 2.2.beta will match prerelease versions like 2.2.beta.12.

[`Read also Ruby's Pessimistic Operator`](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rubys-pessimistic-operator)

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking on @Зелёный's answer to relate the documentation specifically to this question, `'~> 4'` would mean `>= 4` and `< 5.0`.